# How to code an electric sheep oscillator into a raw maths array code C# or C or JavaScript?

Tags: algorithm, audio, fractals

I want to draw a line through an electric sheep display and record it as a waveform to be run at different frequencies. I don't know if it will be anti-aliased, it could be interesting for an LFO source with some after effects and things, I want to hear an electric sheep.

Afterwards, I want to load presets of electric sheep from the community and record them as sounds.

How difficult is it to code and do you have some starting points to hack the electric sheep program and make it export waveforms or something?

Comment: Probably better suited for http://dsp.stackexchange.com, but you'll have to explain it better and ask a specific question. or it'll get closed there.

Comment: I would try http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com as you want to hack in ... if the output is visual then its relatively easy on Windows to obtain the gfx and then conversion to sound depends on how you want to do it but also not that hard .... To output sound correctly is the hardest ... I would use WAVEIN/OUT but that is also Windows specific so if you are on different platform you need to use different api.

Comment: Perhaps i was being too optmistic about a generic idea, natural synthesis generation has balanced groups and ratios of oscillations, and using electric sheep is probably similar in result as using many jpg's from web searches and tracing lines through them... Electric sheep has very many arrays of varied forms and if i can use their balanced and varied ratios i can make some interesting audio from it, except that the ratios are probably difficult to see programatically. timewasting. Best to stick to the project with the simplest work input which produces the most useable results. sorry then.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!